# Feast - How can Snowflake be added as a custom offline store?

Tags: feast

How can Snowflake be added as a custom offline store on Feast? I see a custom implementation to be implemented for Provider Class and offline store class, but how does Feast actually connect to a custom offline store? Should a driver be configured and if so how? The documentation implementation for provider and offline store classes doesn't help me much there.

Is the Feast more improved to support only file, bigquery and redshift at this time for offline feature store? I see mainly only these 3 references for Feast offline store in most implementation, and looks to not have much user base. Please advise, if using Snowflake for offline feature store might be recommendable or not?

Also, how does Feast fair with custom online feature store implementation like Cassandra etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snowflake is now a [fully supported offline data source](https://docs.feast.dev/reference/offline-stores/snowflake) for Feast

```
project: my_feature_repo
registry: data/registry.db
provider: local
offline_store:
  type: snowflake.offline
  account: snowflake_deployment.us-east-1
  user: user_login
  password: user_password
  role: sysadmin
  warehouse: demo_wh
  database: FEAST
```